# jquery data tables disabling sorting not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm having an issue trying to turn off sorting in my DataTables code. Everytime I add "bSort": false I get an ajax error from the datables plugin. But when I take out bSort the table loads without issue.

```
$("#companies").dataTable({
    "bSort": false,
    "bServerSide": true,                // user server side processing
    "sAjaxSource": sohAjaxUrl,          // load data from an external source
    "bProcessing": true,                // enable the processing indicator whilst table is loading
    "searching": false,                 // disable search box
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",       
    "aoColumns": [                      
        { "mDataProp":"itemDescription","bSortable":false,sDefaultContent:"","sWidth":"40%" },
        { "mDataProp":"size","bSortable":false,sDefaultContent:"","sWidth":"15%"  },   
        { "mDataProp":"style","bSortable":false,sDefaultContent:"","sWidth":"15%"  },                     
        { "mDataProp":"supplyStyle","bSortable":false,sDefaultContent:"","sWidth":"15%"  },
        { "mDataProp":"item","bSortable":false,sDefaultContent:"","sWidth":"15%"  }
    ]        
});
```

My end aim is to remove all sorting on all columns. You can see here that the first column is sortable even though I have specified "bSortable":false in the column definition.

[image]

Can someone help me understand why adding bSort causes an ajax error please?

thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `bSort` **and** `bSortable` on every column, as the end result is the same. If you remove `bSort` are the columns still sortable?

Comment: If I remove bsort only the first column remains sortable ( item description) . I'm not sure why it seems to ignore the bsortable flag for the first column

Comment: And what happens if you remove the column-level `bSortable` and keep `bSort`?